# C recursion : return statement

Tags: c, recursion

I just started learning C and I faced the following problem:
in the first **/*recursive step*/** I do not understand why we cannot simply return **multiply(x, y)**? Why do we need to *add a value to y and only then return it?*

The code is below.
Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int multiply(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if (x == 1)
    {
        /* Terminating case */
        return y;
    }
    else if (x > 1)
    {
        /* Recursive step */
        return y + multiply(x-1, y);
    }

    /* Catch scenario when x is zero */
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    printf("3 times 5 is %d", multiply(3, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please remember to "accept" your favourite answer.  This allows SO to properly archive the question, and it gets you a few more points.

Answer (score 2):

If you return **multiply(x, y)**, you will loop forever on the same call parameters.  To have proper recursion, you have to reduce the problem to a simpler case.  That simpler case is to reduce the multiplier by 1.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is simply doing the same operations with smaller inputs. Can we express multiplication of two numbers with smaller numbers ? Sure ! Finding the way to do this is finding a recursive definition of multiplication. First we will try to express x*y with a smaller x, like x-1.
From the simple fact that :

```
(x-1)*y = x*y - y
```

we find :

```
x*y=(x-1)*y + y
```

Remember that we will always have to find a stoping step, here we know that

```
0*y=0
```

and we're done. This gives us even a simpler form of a recursive mul function as the one given by @RobertEagle.

But let us take the thing further. x-1 is smaller than x, as y-1 is smaller than y. Exploring this fact gives us :

```
(x-1)*(y-1)=x*y-x-y+1
x*y = (x-1)*(y-1) + x + y - 1
```

This time the stopping step would be "if x or y is 0 then the result is 0". Translating this into code :

```
unsigned multiply(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
  if ( (x==0) || (y==0) )
    return 0;
  else
    return x+y-1+multiply(x-1, y-1);
}
```

This sort of recursion is not quite efficient because we do not express the recursion with something really smaller. What if we try to halve one of the parameters ?
If x is even we can write :

```
x*y=2*(x/2)*y=(x/2)*(2*y)
```

If x is odd we can write :

```
x*y=(x-1+1)*y=(x-1)*y+y=((x-1)/2)*(2*y)+y
```

Multiplying (resp. dividing) by 2 can be achieved with left (resp. right) shifting :

```
unsigned multiply(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
  if (x==0)
    return 0;
  else if (x%2==0)
    return multiply(x>>1, y<<1);
  else
    return y+multiply((x-1)>>1, y<<1);
}
```

This method will take less steps than the first one. The "more" you're getting smaller, the "more" you're getting faster, in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't add the value, it would simply return `y` as the final result of the top most recursive call.

X * Y = X, Y times

e.g.  4 * 5 = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4

This logic is expanding that evaluation, and just returning the last value would only evaluate to Y one time.

Answer (score 0):

Every recursive function is made up of 2 elements:

1. The repetitive condition
2. The stopping condition

Without a stopping condition, the program would enter an infinite loop.
In this case, it would mean the program would continually call beyond `x == 1`.

Instead of stopping calling itself at `x == 1`, the program would also call `multiply(-1,y)`, `multiply(-2,y)` ... to infinite.

Ultimately, you need to sum the **y** for **x** times. And to do this you need to return **x** times the value of **y**. And in this case, the repetitive condition adds **y** for **x-1** times and for the stopping condition you only need one more time.

You also could have done it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int multiply(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        /* Terminating case */
        return 0;
    }
    else if (x > 0)
    {
        /* Recursive step */
        return y + multiply(x-1, y);
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("3 times 5 is %d", multiply(3, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

Here you can see the repetitive is concerted with adding the **y** for exactly **x** times. Logically, the stopping condition would require to return 0, because we don't need to add anymore the **y** value. We already have added it for **x** times.